# REGEXP_REPLACE special character

Tags: sql, oracle

I have varchar lastname (Jovic) and I need to replace the letter **c** to **ć** .

I tried with regexp_replace but no results. does anyone know how to replace?

Comment: Should be as simple as `regexp_replace('Jovic' , 'c', 'ć')`

Comment: Hi, could you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace('Jovic' , 'c', 'ć') from dual;
```

should return name with replaced character. In case it doesn't please check encoding set for your client application operating system maybe it is not able to display such character (I can't believe it)

If by replace you mean replace it in your database please follow suggestions by **MT0**

Answer (score 2):

Just do a replace:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET   lastname = 'Jović'
WHERE lastname = 'Jovic';
```

If you need to replace a word within multiple names then:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET   lastname = REGEXP_REPLACE( lastname, '(^|\W)Jovic(\W|$)', '\1Jović\2' )
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( lastname, '(^|\W)Jovic(\W|$)' );
```